# What does this Javascript line do

Tags: javascript, react-redux

I´m new to javascript and React and wonder simple question what does this line of code do?

I have search about the () and => but dont understand

'`export const increment = () => ({ type: "INC" });`'

I know the `increment` variable here will holde the type: "INC" as an array I think but what about the = () =>

Comment: Exports a function called increment, that returns the object. Import it, and call increment() to see the value

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested on [ask].

Comment: @scniro Why is it a function? The word "function" is not used?

Comment: makes a function called `increment` which returns the object `{type: "INC"}`

Comment: @jurgebent () => is called an arrow function. It's short hand for function() {  }.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). Arrow functions were introduced in ECMAScript 6 and support is relatively recent.

This statement, for example:

```
export const increment = () => ({ type: "INC" });
```

exports a function named `increment`. The function takes no arguments, and returns this JavaScript object literal:

```
{
    type: "INC"
}
```

The same statement would be written as follows prior to ES 6:

```
exports.increment = function () {
    return {
        type: "INC"
    }
}
```

Comment: So whenever I see '() =>' I can (in my mind) replace it with 'function ()'. Ok yea that is a function nice shortcut

Comment: see there was already a good question about this thanks